# How can I create tmpfs on AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an application that is very IO sensitive that I want to host on AWS lambda. I want to use the up to 10GB memory that lambda functions can now have, create a tmpfs and serve my incoming requests using data there.

Unfortunately, I am not able to figure a way to do this.

Among other things, i have tried to create a tmpfs and load it both from my dockerfile or by invoking it from python. But these look like they need sudo access.

Would anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: The available, up to 10GB /tmp ephemeral storage being insufficient performance presumably?

Comment: Lambda is not necessarily the right answer for every problem.  If you require this much O/S level customization perhaps an EC2 that auto scales could be better.

Comment: @stdunbar lambda has everything i need in terms of capability. the requests are may be a dozen a minute and each request takes about a second to process. Having a EC2 with 10G of memory up and running all the while is sub optimal for my use case.

Comment: As an example, i expect about 20k seconds of usage over a week long period (~600k seconds) or a little over 3% utilization. Easy to see why having an EC2 running all the time is super wasteful.

Comment: **Side-note:** The container running the Lambda function can 'disappear' after a period of non-use, so it would not be a good way of storing persistent data. It is fine if the function is being called often. Also, the AWS Lambda service might create _multiple containers_ if the function is invoked while another instance of the function is running, so you should limit the function to having a **concurrency of 1** to ensure the same container is always used. You might enjoy reading: [Lambda Optimization](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, these are valid considerations. In my case I will package the data along with my function. if tmpfs is empty, i can always copy the data from the working directory and move forward. The data is read only. it is essentially lookups and some processing at its core. I will likely need concurrent containers too. So that's a plus. 

10GB each of container storage and RAM is awesome. I can even read it from S3 if tmpfs is empty. Not a big deal.

Comment: **A word about cost:** AWS Lambda is charged per GB-second. Thus, requesting 10GB of RAM will cost 80x the price of using 128MB. An alternative would be to expand the `/tmp/` disk storage to 10GB, which is 1/5th the cost of expanding the RAM. It won't be as fast as tmpfs, but it is much simpler to implement.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i already have 2 cofings setup - a Lambda that reads from S3 and serves the requests, a spot instance that stores everything in memory and serves. Neither is optimal for low but bursty usage. Lambda with tempfs is the best if i can make it work. In fact i have about 25 gigs of data i need to lookup from, but can partition it into 5 or 6 lambdas leaving some RAM for processing.

Comment: Memory == RAM. Storage == disk space. You keep saying "memory" and "file system" in the same sentences. Are you talking about Lambda ephemeral storage https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/ or are you talking about the configured function memory? Are you allocating 10GB RAM to the function and trying to create a ramdisk? Was the 10GB ephemeral SSD storage not fast enough?

Comment: @MarkB yes, the SSD storage is not fast enough. I am trying to create a ram disk, which I do with an ec2 instance now. Trying to use the memory in lambda function the same way.

Comment: Yeah you won't be able to do a ramdisk in Lambda, as the process your function runs as won't have permission. You should look into other ways to load that data into memory.

Comment: @MarkB These are parquet files I am looking to store in memory as compressed data. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you doing with the parquet files? Querying them with Pandas or something? Can't you just load them into dataframes in memory?

Comment: Yes, when you load them into a data frame, it's uncompressed. So I just load the partitions I care about at runtime, depending on incoming request.